# Localize code behind Controls with MarkupExtension

Tags: wpf, localization

I am working on localization with a WPF C# project in VS2010. I need to change the language in the whole software programmatically.

Using `MarkupExtension` I can localize XAML text to different language. I wonder if `MarkupExtension` can also change text in dynamically generated Control content?

for example:

```
button.Content = "Some Other language of text";
```